# React state sets the same value to all of the state values

Tags: reactjs, setstate

I'm new to react JS, I'm trying to get the values from a form, and send it to a node JS middleware.
I set up two values in the state, one for the email and another one for the password. I set the state for both values in the set state method.

```
      class LoginForm extends Component {
        
          constructor(props){
            super(props)
        
            this.state = {
              email : '',
              password : '',
            }
        
          }
         
          handleChange = (e) => {
        
            this.setState({ email : e.target.value, password : e.target.value})   
          }
        
        
          handleSubmit = (e) => {
            
            console.log('state', this.state)
            
          };


render () {
    return (
      <div style = {styles.form} >
      <Fragment>
        <Form
          {...layout}
          name="basic"
          initialValues={{
            remember: true,
          }}
          onFinish={this.handleSubmit}
        >
              <Form.Item
                  name="email"
                  rules={[
                    {
                      type: 'email',
                      message: 'The input is not valid E-mail!',
                    },
                    {
                      required: true,
                      message: 'Please input your E-mail!',
                    },
                  ]}
                  hasFeedback
                >
                    <Input
                    placeholder={t`Email`}
                    value={this.state.email}
                    onChange={this.handleChange} />
                
                </Form.Item>

          <Form.Item
            name="password"
            rules={[{ required: true }]} hasFeedback
          >
            <Input.Password 
                placeholder={t`Password`}
                value={this.state.password}
                onChange={this.handleChange}
            />
          </Form.Item>

          <Button 
                type="primary"
                htmlType="submit"
              >
                <span style = {styles.button} >Sign in</span>
          </Button>
        </Form>
        </Fragment>      
    </div>
    )
  }
}


    }
```

I created the handle submit function and linked it to the onsubmit method inside the form and tried console logging the current state of my values inside the handle submit function. To my surprise the value from the password gets console logged for the value email too. Like this

```
state {email: "123", password: "123"}
```

I cannot figure out what am I doing wrong.

Comment: have a different handlers for `email` and `password` , and `setState` accordingly ... for e.g. `handleEmailChange` for email and `handlePasswordChange` for password

Comment: Thank you so much for the help, I was able to console log two different values for email and password if I create two separate handlers. But the older method should have yielded the same result right. Or should it not? im confused!

Comment: The thing is an event is bind and unique to each event handler , so the respective target value is the value of the one which is clicked ... to be simple can we click on two different elements at once -> `NO` so why would we expect both values in same event handler ? hope its clear !! :)

Comment: Ahh, this makes much more sense now, thanks a lot for helping me figuring out this, appreciate it!!

Comment: Your handler takes the value of e.target.value and sets it as both the email and password properties in your state.  A common pattern that you see with forms is to set a single property where the property name is a variable, like this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value }).  You would need to set the name property on your input elements for that to work.  Like name=“email” and name=“password”.

Comment: @LindaPaiste It's much more clear now ! thanks and this would be the way to go and also uses one single handler ... :)

Comment: Thanks for the solution @LindaPaiste, I set a value for name property and tried setting the state with your method, but I was able to return an empty object.

Answer (score 1):

I think if you change your `handleChange` function to this, it should work.

```
handleChange = (e) => {
            this.setState({ [e.target.id] : e.target.value})   
        }
```

And add `id` to the input fields like this

```
<Input id="email" placeholder={t`Email`} value={this.state.email} onChange {this.handleChange} />

<Input.Password id="password" placeholder={t`Password`} value {this.state.password} onChange={this.handleChange} />
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution:

```
handleChange = (e) => {
    let email = ''
    let password = ''

    if (e.target.name === 'email') {
        email = e.taget.value
    } else {
        password = e.taget.value
    }
    
    this.setState({ email, password})   
}
```

Comment: You r welcome. As this was helpful, will you please upvote & mark as accepted :) It will boost my motivation 